# IOS 12.4 didReceiveRemoteNotification method not called. objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, firebase, push-notification

I have put the same code of my another application and run but this time didReceiveRemoteNotification method did not call and all certificate set properly even this didReceiveRemoteNotification not called.

Token register successfully. and print also device token but add device token to sent notification not received.

And I test real device my iPhone ios version is 12.4.

how to solve this error please help me.

Now became a new error Failed to fetch default token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=0 "(null)"

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    [FIRApp configure];

    [FIRMessaging messaging].delegate = self;

    //self.window.rootViewController = self.mainNavigationController;

    if (@available(iOS 10.0, *)) {
        if ([UNUserNotificationCenter class] != nil) {
            [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = self;
            UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptionAlert |
            UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
            [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter]
             requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions
             completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {

             }];
        } else {
            // iOS 10 notifications aren't available; fall back to iOS 8-9 notifications.
            UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
            (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
            UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
            [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
            [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        }
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }

    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];

    return YES;
}

- (void)messaging:(FIRMessaging *)messaging didReceiveRegistrationToken:(NSString *)fcmToken {
    NSLog(@"FCM registration token: %@", fcmToken);
    // Notify about received token.
    NSDictionary *dataDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:fcmToken forKey:@"token"];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:
     @"FCMToken" object:nil userInfo:dataDict];
    // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
    // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
}

// With "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled": NO
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    [FIRMessaging messaging].APNSToken = deviceToken;
}


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    // Print message ID.
    if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
        NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
    }

    [self application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:^(UIBackgroundFetchResult result) {
    }];

    // Print full message.
    NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);

}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {


    // Print message ID.
    if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
        NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
    }

    // Print full message.
    NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);


    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
```

Comment: Did you check .pem file ?

Comment: @Nij I have checked it and it is fine

Comment: Are you using the production or sandbox push sever? Have you ever successfully implemented push notifications before? It can be a quite tedious thing to get working properly in the beginning... Can you check your push server for errors?